# How to create a reversed Bottom Sheet from the top in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bottom-sheet

I need to implement a reversed bottom sheet which should be sliding from the **top of the parent view to the bottom**.I have done my research and found plenty of supported libraries, but all of them don't work with sliding from the top of the view. I have tried to apply translation and **reverse a drawer layout by 180 degrees** in [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley), but it created issues with safe area in iPhoneX for example.

Perhaps I am overcomplicating things with manually editing libraries, but I would like to get possible solutions or sample codes for creating this particular UI.

It should be done with regular interface builder in code, **not in Swift UI** at the moment.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is create it manually?
It's not that hard to create a black overlay that animates in while having a rounded corners white view animating from the top?

I think editing existing libraries to make it work is more work than doing this yourself? :)
I can supply some code if you need it but perhaps try it yourself and come back with your code and I can help update it to make it work properly?

Comment: please, rather supply some code sample. I have tried different solutions with different libraries, it won't be easy to explain :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but SO should be used to learn and not simply copy-paste code others provide. If you supply some code you've written yourself I'll be happy to help you improve it.